# How to find data between two columns with Sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just learning Sql. I have a data with column names, for example: nkk, name, tps. How to find same 'nkk' data but different 'tps'

[image]

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT, DISTINCT

Comment: I have tried it, but haven't found the right formula

Comment: Show us your current attempt.

Comment: What result do you expect (out of that data)? Which database do you really use? Is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Littlefoot I used Oracle

Comment: You have this question tagged both MySQL and Oracle. Which are you actually using?

Comment: @Barmar I use both, I'm studying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join whose joining condition is exactly what you described: `nkk` is equal, but `tps` is not equal.

```
SELECT t1.nkk, t1.name AS name1, t1.tps AS tps1, t2.name AS name2, t2.tps AS tps2
FROM your_table AS t1
JOIN your_table AS t2 ON t1.nkk = t2.nkk AND t1.tps < t2.tps
```

I use `<` rather than `!=` so we only get one of each pair. Otherwise you'll get both `Aa Ac` and `Ac Aa`.

Comment: It can work fine, but I'm missing two pieces of data with names 'AD' and 'CC'

Comment: I don't see that in your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
    SELECT nkk, count(DISTINCT tps) AS c 
        FROM `tblname` 
        GROUP BY nkk 
        HAVING c > 1 
        ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` should be `COUNT(DISTINCT tps)`